# In Azure DocumentDB / CosmosDB, is it possible to get random sample?

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I'm looking for functionality similar to [$sample in mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/), but it doesn't seem to be supported in Azure's Cosmos DB. Is there any other way to get a random subset (up to a specified size of documents)? Something like the logic of SQL's

```
SELECT col FROM table 
ORDER BY Random()
LIMIT 100;
```

could also work?

Answer (score 1):

The Aggregation Framework is not a supported query construct today. You'd need to come up with your own scheme for randomizing output, as there is no built-in randomization method for documents being returned.

Comment: Would this help https://medium.com/@murdockcrc/documentdb-retrieving-a-random-document-7ef4a27e8591